# Why main thread gets hanged when background worker is executing

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I have simple winforms application where i have button. on button click i am doing something like this

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw_Convert = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw_Convert.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw_Convert.DoWork += bw_Convert_DoWork;
        bw_Convert.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_Convert_RunWorkerCompleted;
        bw_Convert.ProgressChanged += bw_Convert_ProgressChanged;
        bw_Convert.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw_Convert.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

I have following code for background worker

```
   public void bw_Convert_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++)
        {                
            bw_Convert.ReportProgress((100 * (i) / 1000));
        }
    }
    public void bw_Convert_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {           

        progressBarControl1.EditValue = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
    }
```

By doing this. Why my Main Thread gets hanged as i m processing the things in Background Worker.

Comment: How could you know that the main thread hanged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [ReportProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4.aspx) event handler is executed on main thread:

> The call to the ReportProgress method is asynchronous and returns
>   immediately. The ProgressChanged event handler executes on the thread
>   that created the BackgroundWorker.

Thus you are constantly calling `ReportProgress` from background thread, it makes your main thread constantly busy handling this event.

If you have a lot of quick work to do in background, then try to report only each n-th iteration instead of raising event on each iteration:

```
public void bw_Convert_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++)
    {   
        if (i % 10000 == 0)
           bw_Convert.ReportProgress(i);
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ProgressChanged` event is executed on the UI thread so you can access the controls.
The code inside your background worker is executing in a very short amount of time, leading to many events being raised in a short period of time, making the code react as if it would execute completely on the UI thread.

In fact, most of the work *is* being done in the UI thread, because updating a control on the screen is much more work than the loop iterations.